# How to display a gif in the middle of a div page in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div, which acts as a page, and it only has a gif. Though the gif appears at the upper left corner of the page. I want to make it appear in the middle of the page. Below you can find my HTML and CSS that I tried, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
<div id="correctGIF" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="false">
    <img src="images/correct.gif">
</div>

.correctGIF > img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your div is the size of the page and has `position:relative` then

```
#correctGIF > img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    display:block;
}
```

will get you **most** of the way.

However, what it does is put the top/left corner of the image at the 50% position and so it is not **exactly** centered.

If you know the size of the image you can adjust it with negative margins like so

```
margin-top: - [Insert 50% of image height] px;
margin-left: - [Insert 50% of image width] px;
```

So, for instance

```
margin-top: -100px;
margin-left: -100px;
```

for a 200x200 image.

If you do NOT know the size of the image (perhaps you'll be changing it often) then you can dispense with the negative margins and just use.

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

This adjusts the final position of the image based on its OWN dimensions regardless of what they might be.

Answer (score 0):

You are using class selector instead of id selector in css. 
You can change that to id selector as:

```
#correctGIF > img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
```

Alternatively, you can apply a styling to div to display as table and center it then:

```
<div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="false">
<img src="images/correct.gif">
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

wrong css selector

```
#correctGIF > img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
```