# Issue to center a div horizontally

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to center my div .down-arrow horizontally but without success. The DIV is absolute positioned but margin:0px auto; does not seem to be working. What is the issue? thanks
http://jsfiddle.net/7UNrP/

HTML:

```
  <header>
<div class="down-arrow">arrow</div>

    </header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-1020-711-1.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);
}
.down-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    margin:0px auto;
    bottom: 20px;
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    border: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-animation: icon 1.2s infinite;
}


@-webkit-keyframes icon {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
        bottom: 20px;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
        bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't told the arrow div where to be except `bottom:20px` so it defaults to `left:0;`

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7UNrP/11/)

You need to add this to your arrow CSS

```
left:50%; /*push the div halfway over*/
-webkit-transform:translateX(-50%); /* bring it back by half its own width */
transform:translateX(-50%);
```

You might want to refer to this post which had much the same issue. I go into further detail regarding this solution.

[**Reference Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23854966/how-to-display-a-gif-in-the-middle-of-a-div-page-in-jquery/23855153#23855153)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to using `margin:0 auto` with the `display:inline` and `position: absolute`. You can easily center it by applying `text-align:center`  to the `header` as your inner content has an `inline` layout.

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/7UNrP/3/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but for some reason it does not work in live environment, see here: http://goo.gl/rIFzou Would you know why?

Comment: @Greg : I guess it happens so because there is a mix of `inline` and `block` elements.Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7UNrP/10/) can work out.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately with this solution the div is not perfectly horizontally aligned, it's a few px more to the right. I'll go for Paulie's solution. Thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
text-align:center;
```

in `header` css like this

```
header {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 600px;
min-height: 300px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-1020-711-1.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
background-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);
text-align: center;
}
```

EDIT:

This aligns the .down-arrow div in the center horizontally and keep it 20 pixel away from the bottom side of the its container

```
   .down-arrow {
position: absolute;
margin-left: 50%;
/* bottom: 20px; */
/* display: inline; */
padding: 10px;
color: #FFF;
border: 0;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 12px;
background: red;
-webkit-animation: icon 1.2s infinite;
}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but for some reason it does not work in live environment, see here: http://goo.gl/rIFzou Would you know why?

Comment: Could you show us live url? Also try text-align:center !important;

Comment: See here: http://goo.gl/rIFzou Tks I've just tried to add  !important;  but doesn't change anything

Comment: @Greg Try to use position: relative; in .down-arrow this should solve the problem. PS: Look at edit in my answer. I hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately with position:relative the div is not placed 20px from the bottom of it's container

Comment: @Greg Hi, you wrote in your question "I'm trying to center my div .down-arrow horizontally but without success", so I suppose you would like the div in the center? Do you want also the div 20 up from the bottom of its container? So please edit your question.

Comment: @Greg I have edited my question. Please let me know if it works as you expected :-)